# Angular material different background themes

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is there any way to achieve different background colors for different themes?

I have for a default theme:

```
.backgroundPalette('brown')
```

but for this situations all other small elements for example datepicker gets this brown background.

For only **some** elements works method when I declared a new theme for elements

```
$mdThemingProvider
  .theme('elements')
  .backgroundPalette('grey');
```

and use them for specific element as

```
md-theme="elements"
```

Comment: What is your question? You basically already provided the answer.

Comment: No, there isn't an answer cuz as I wrote, this method(md-theme) only works for few elements not for all and I want to maybe another method if is possible.

Comment: Then please provide a codepen or something that shows a working and a not working example.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVdPrV?editors=1010
datepicker element even if has md-theme don't change appearance, but autocomplete does

Comment: Not sure whats happening there, should have been fixed in https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8690

Comment: no, this's in module file, and doesn't affect on this behavior